# Ask user to check categories of an item and then display category-specific options

Tags: forms, wizard

**Problem**

In my Web application I have a form in which the user must fill some information about a generic item, let's say a **car**. Between all the standard information (name, description etc) I am asking the user to check the categories of which the item belongs according to the his/her belief (e.g. "Sport Car", "Subcompact Car" etc).

Now based on the category checked I need to ask additional information to the user. For example if he/she checks "Sport Car" I need to show another form asking for "Sport Car"-related informations (e.g. top speed) whereas for a "Subcompact car" category the average consumption.

---

**Possible Solution**

Let the user fill the car form (with the categories checkboxes) then the system will store the car object in the database with its checked categories. After that, the user can specify the category-related information in a special page say "Advanced Options" which based on the categories of the object will show all the category-related form.

Still I am not convinced since I would like to make the category-related informations mandatory if the relative category is checked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you think you can't make the category items mandatory?

Comment: TL;DR: Multi-Steps Form. Otherwise this handling is way to complex and confusing. Even I had to read it twice

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you want to ask the same information about all types?  Surely, if this is intended to be an informative database (maybe it isn't?), sports car researchers would like to know miles/km per gal/liter just as much as someone researching compact cars would like to know top and most-economical cruising speeds.

Answer (score 0):

**Allow Multiple Category selection of user choice,Which can be a multi select** option.

example:
- Sports Car
- SUV
- Others

This will be a category for types of car,
 and in same form have other options as speed and mileage and other options.

Also showing the number of results found when each filter is selected/
De-selected will keep user in context about results.

If there is a case for No result found for a specific filter selection show 0 result found for user , So user can modify the filter.

All this Numbers should be shown before user applies filter.(i.e in realtime )

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to the Advanced options page would be to dynamically display additional Sport car-related form fields next to the Category checkboxes. That way the user can see the additional questions you want to ask in context.